# PHP : Using single quotes and double quotes in single string

Tags: php

How can i use string like below code.

```
$str = 'Is yo"ur name O'reil"ly?';
```

The above code is just an example..I need to use big html template which contains single and double quotes.I tried **Addslashes** php method but when i use single and double quote string in that function i get syntax error.Please help me.

Note : my realtime usage is json data like below.

```
    $string = "

    <html>
    ...
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    ..

    ";
   $string = '{"method":"template","params":{"1":"'.$string.'"},"token":"12345"}';
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for that:

```
$string = <<<EOM
    <html>
    ...
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    ..
EOM;
```

If you wish to prevent variable interpolation as well you can use [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) (since 5.3):

```
$string = <<<'EOM'
    <html>
    ...
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    ..
EOM;
```

Both heredoc and nowdoc have specific formatting requirements, so be sure to read the manual properly.

Comment: You might also mention that there are no spaces / tabs allowed before the ending of a heredoc.

Comment: @Luceos Variable work just fine in heredoc. See this example - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-73

Comment: Jep, i know; typo; temp's been rising at office xD

Comment: @user2425700 that's if you use `$variable` inside the heredoc, just like inside double quotes, e.g. `"hello $variable"`.

Comment: @user2425700 Btw, since you're relatively new to the scene, read the [about] section on how to accept answers.

Answer (score 2):

I used heredoc to do the same like

```
$string = <<< EOF
'Is yo"ur name O'reil"ly?'
EOF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [heredoc](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) like this:

```
$str = <<< EOF
'Is yo"ur name O'reil"ly?'
EOF;
```