# PHP substring in double quotes

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a PHP string 
$str='Hi this is "a string" and I "need to extract" the sub strings "that are inside" double quotes'.

I wish to extract the sub strings from this PHP string that are contained inside double quotes.

I would like to know as to how do I go about this problem.
Thanks

Comment: `$array = array_column(array_chunk(explode('"', $string), 2), 1);`

Comment: This question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793678/php-using-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-single-string ) might help:  or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793678/php-using-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-single-string) :

Answer (score 0):

Try this using **strstr** and **strrpos**:

```
$str='Hi this is "a string" in php';
$newStr = strstr($str, '"');
echo substr($newStr, 0, strrpos ($newStr, '"'));
```